# Correct way to use variable name with subset within purrr::pmap in R?

Tags: r, subset, purrr

I have a tibble called `description`:

```
description <- structure(list(col1 = "age", col2 = "> 7 months", col3 = "<= 7 months"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

> description
# A tibble: 1 × 3
  col1  col2       col3       
  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      
1 age   > 7 months <= 7 months
```

And a data frame called `my_df`:

```
my_df <- structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6"
), age = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("<= 7 months", 
"> 7 months"), class = "factor")), row.names = c("ID1", "ID2", 
"ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6"), class = "data.frame")

> my_df
     ID         age
ID1 ID1 <= 7 months
ID2 ID2  > 7 months
ID3 ID3 <= 7 months
ID4 ID4  > 7 months
ID5 ID5  > 7 months
ID6 ID6  > 7 months
```

I currently have the following function:

```
updated_df <- purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
        subset(
            my_df,
            age == col2
        )
})
```

This produces:

```
[[1]]
     ID        age
ID2 ID2 > 7 months
ID4 ID4 > 7 months
ID5 ID5 > 7 months
ID6 ID6 > 7 months
```

But I would like to use the variable `col1` instead of `age`. I have tried the following, but they don't work:

```
updated_df <- purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
        subset(
            my_df,
            col1 == col2
        )
})


updated_df <- purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
        subset(
            my_df,
            !!as.name(col1) == col2
        )
})

updated_df <- purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
        subset(
            my_df,
            !!col1 == col2
        )
})
```

Where am I going wrong / what is the correct way to use `col1` instead of `age`?

Comment: `col1` is not a variable in `my_df`?

Comment: col1 is mapped to "age" in description tibble

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay within `subset` you'd need to capture and evaluate the full expression. E.g.

```r
purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
  subset(
    my_df,
    eval(rlang::expr(!!rlang::ensym(col1) == col2))
  )
})
```

If you're open for using `dplyr::filter` instead of `subset`, you can do:

```r
purrr::pmap(description, function(col1, col2, col3) {
  dplyr::filter(
                my_df,
                !!rlang::ensym(col1) == col2
                )
})
```